# Change border color and appearance for WinForms control

Tags: c#, winforms

When the user will hover the label, it will add a `top-border` and `bottom-border` to the label.

Something similar to this: http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ -> Border Transitions
-> Underline From Center.

However, I only know how to define the normal border. I can't even change the color of the border, his width and more...

This is what I achieved so far:

**designer.cs:**

```
this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(124, 187);
this.label1.Name = "label1";
this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(217, 65);
this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
this.label1.Text = "Something Cool";
this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
this.label1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_MouseHover);
this.label1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_MouseLeave);
```

**cs:**

```
private void label1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 18, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // initialize
    label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Comment: This is a much bigger thing than you realize.  You will have to inherit the control into your own.  Take over the `Paint` handler, and draw this yourself.  You will have to respond to all user inputs and react accordingly, drawing everything you wish to see happen.  This will not be an easy project.  If you still have the choice, you would find that WPF makes this sort of thing much easier.

Comment: It isn't that hard to do in `WinForms` though. You don't need to touch inheritance at all.

Comment: @L.Guthardt Hi, thanks. I did: `ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);`and it really stroke all the label, but i wants it to be only on top and bottom, how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first I suggest you to use the `label1_MouseEnter()` event instead of the `label1_MouseHover()` event. Since the hover event constantly fires while you are hovering `label1`. Thats unnecessary because you will change the looking of `label1` just when you enter the label and change it back to the default one, once you leave it. So `MouseEnter()` is your preferred choice.

We will define a `bool` variable to check if a surroinding border shell be drawn around `label1`. We change it's value in the `MouseEnter()` and `MouseLeave()` event.

```
bool changeBorder;
```

In those events we will call `label1.Refresh()`, which redraws the control, so it's `Paint()` event will be fired.

```
private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    changeBorder = true;
    label1.Refresh();
}

private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    changeBorder = false;
    label1.Refresh();
}
```

Now we validate if a new *special border* shell be drawn or not. If so we use the [ControlPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint(v=vs.110).aspx) class with it's [DrawBorder()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder(v=vs.110).aspx) method to draw a custom border of the size of `label1`'s `Rectangle`. You can modify this border as you wish to. If we don't want to draw this *special border*, we draw a *default* border. What simply has the color of the `Form`'s Backcolor, so it seems like there isn't any border around `label1`.

```
private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (changeBorder)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle,
                      Color.Red, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                      Color.Red, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                      Color.Red, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                      Color.Red, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
    else
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, this.BackColor, ButtonBorderStyle.None);
    }
```

In the method parameters for `ControlPaint.DrawBorder()` be aware of the `0` instead of the `2`. The parameters of `ControlPaint.DrawBorder()` for the *rectangles width* are as followed:

1. `int leftWidth`
2. `int topWidth`
3. `int rightWidth`
4. `int bottowmWidth`

That's why I set as the first and third the value `0` so no border will be drawn on the right and left side. You can adjust that according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally understand your code and explanntions. I have one more question, is it possible to do those functions (`label1_Paint` & `label1_MouseEnter` & `label1_MouseLeave`) to be good with all labels? I meant, if I have some labels, I do not wants to do all of them to each of ones. I want that all three will handle all of the labels, so how I can do it? I guess I should trigger which label is enter, or leave, but how I can achieve it? Thanks!!!

Comment: You have to subscribe to each `myLabel_MouseEnter()`, `myLabel_MouseLeave()` and `myLabel_Paint()` event of each single label. Since just one specific event fires once one action happens on this particular control. But e.g. you can write a method that all `Paint()` events will call. So you subscribe to all the `Paint()` events but all those events call the same extern method which was defined by you. This extern method needs the `PaintEventArgs e` as method paramether to be able to draw the rectagnle to the specific control.

Comment: If I understand correctly, make a general Paint function that recieve PaintEventArgs e, and in each labelX_paint just call him and pass the PaintEventArgs e of the function. Yes? Thanks again

Comment: Exactly. I believe you could create a custom control as well: `public class CustomLabel : Label`. Then modify already it's `Paint` method in this class. Furthermore in your code remove the namespace from this class. This way this control will be shown in the `ToolBox`, so you can drag and drop the control just like all the default controls onto your `Form`. You will still have to  do `labelX.Refresh()` but the border painting will be already implemented for each label you create of this custom control class. And you can use this `CustomLabel` just as a normal `Label` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the border color, create a panel with a 1px padding and put label1 inside of that panel.  When you want to change the border color, instead, change the color of the panel.